# Remove duplicate by row(only the same columns)

Tags: r, data.table

I know there are many ways, but they are not suitable for my requirements.

I found unique, duplicated, distinct, but these seem to be compared to other columns/rows.

What I want is two data comparisons of the same columns.

```
DT <- data.table(first=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D"),
              second=c("A","B","D","B","D","C","A"),
              value=c(90,47,189,72,42,86,280))
```

I want to find the value of first and the value of second. If they are the same, delete them (only the same columns)

output:

```
     first second value
 1     A      B     47
 2     A      D    189
 3     B      D     42
 4     D      A    280
```

I use these methods and just return the same data

```
DT <- unique(DT, by=c('first','second'))
DT <- DT[!duplicated(DT[,c("first","second")]),]
DT <- distinct(DT, first, second, .keep_all= TRUE)
```

Maybe the method is simple? It’s just that I think it’s too complicated.

Comment: Your example data is incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really simple using data.table!

```
DT[first != second,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just ?

```
DT[first != second, ]

#   first second value
#1:     A      B    47
#2:     A      D   189
#3:     B      D    42
#4:     D      A   280
```

`duplicated`, `unique` perform row-wise computation, here we want to compare column1 with column2 so basic comparison operator using `!=` would suffice.